# C# unit test with Moq behaves differently when run alone to when run as part of a set

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test which verifies (using Moq), how many times a particular function was called. It should be called twice.

When you right-click on it in Visual Studio and run it, the test passes. When you run the entire suite - including this test - this test, and only this test, fails, saying the function was only called once.

There are no setup or teardown functions to run for this test - just the mock repository and a few lines of test code.

When right-clicking to run the test, I can debug it and verify that the function is question is indeed called twice. But as far as I know, I can't run an entire test suite in debug mode.

How can I find out why this test is behaving differently in the single and the suite run?

EDIT: code. I'm verifying the SaveChanges() method

```
public override void SaveChanges()
{
    bool isNew = CurrentCampaign.IsNewCampaign;
    DocTreeViewModel.SaveChanges(); //this method posted below

    using (IRepository r = Rep.Renew())
    {
        foreach (Quote quote in CurrentCampaign.Quotes)
        {
            r.Update(quote);
        }

        r.SaveChanges(); // called here
    }

    if (isNew)
    {
        CreateScheduleDocument();
    }
}

// this is the code in DocTreeViewModel.SaveChanges
public override void SaveChanges()
{
    using(IRepository r = Rep.Renew())
    {
        // Flatten is an extension method to flatten a recursive tree
        foreach(DocumentCategory dc in DocumentCategories.Flatten()) 
        {
            r.Update(dc);
        }

        r.SaveChanges(); //called here
    }
}

// mock setup
private Mock<IRepository> GetMockRepository()
{
    Mock<IRepository> repMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
    repMock.Setup(m => m.Renew()).Returns(repMock.Object);

    repMock.Setup(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<Campaign>())).Verifiable();

    repMock.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges()).Verifiable();

    ItemType it1 = new ItemType { ItemTypeId = 1 };
    repMock.Setup(m => m.GetItemTypes()).Returns((new List<ItemType> { it1 }).AsQueryable);

    return repMock;
}

//test
[TestMethod]
public void Assert_SignOff_ChangesStatusEnum()
{
    Mock<IRepository> repMock = GetMockRepository();
    CampaignOverviewViewModel vm = new CampaignOverviewViewModel(new Campaign(), repMock.Object, new Mock<IMsgBoxService>().Object);

    vm.SignOff(); //this calls SaveChanges
    Assert.AreEqual(CampaignStatus.Signed, vm.CurrentCampaign.StatusEnum);
    repMock.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what version of VS you are using, but you can run the test suite in debug mode in 2013. In 2013 it is Test>Debug>All Tests

Comment: @sign oh neat. Thanks - I had no idea that was there. It's hitting the function twice, but Moq is claiming it's only been once.

Comment: Post the code, it's probably something funky with the optimizer causing it to only get run once in production mode.

Comment: This sounds like a scoping issue with your mock, you should include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in your question.

Comment: @sign - done, thanks

Comment: I assume you are configuring your mock in GetMockRepository method - could you post that as well?

Comment: @jjczopek I'd posted the relevant line from that method to verify SaveChanges - have added the full function. Thanks.

Comment: I put together what should be a minimal reproduction case but it works as expected. https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6yyVl